# exceljs nmFmt currency variable

Tags: currency, exceljs

I am using exceljs and numFmt to display a currency, but the currency isn't just dollars, it isn't just '$' - the currency symbol can change, the currency is a variable.  How do I get this to display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript template literals and wrap the variable in double quotes:

```
cell.numFmt = `"${currencySymbol}"###,###,###,##0,`
```